# Считывание количества подряд введенных символов со строки

Tags: java

Как посчитать количество подряд введенных символов в строку?
В интернете много ответов на тему как посчитать кол-во одинаковых символов в строке, но чтобы подряд, ничего не нашел.

Хочу реализовать решение небольшой задачки, где при введении одинаковых символов подряд переменная увеличивается на 1.

Может имеются какие-либо специальные методы, или кого-нибудь есть понимание как это реализовать?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    // 01 10

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            String string = sc.nextLine();
            } else if (string.equals("10")) {
                a = a + 1;
            } else if (string.equals("01")) {
                b = b + 1;
            }


             if(string вводится пару раз подряд) то
                например переменная int k = k +1;        
}

    }
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить... Предположим у вас такая строка - abddccdddefg. В ней с встречается дважды, а d встречается дважды и трижды, если считать подряд. Какой именно символ считать в этом случае. И , если это d, то результат должен быть 2 или 3?

Comment: В общем достаточно сложно объяснить алгоритм, но попробую:
Вводится число с клавиатуры в строку например 10, причем несколько раз, и пока вводится 10, то переменная типа int должна ровняться например 0, как только будет введено 01, переменная прибавляет 1

Comment: Вводится `aa/aa/bb/bb/bb/aa/aa/aa` (`/` это перевод строки). Что должно быть в результате?

Comment: сразу после aa/aa как только ввелось bb некая переменная int a увеличивается на 1

Comment: есть текущая строка и предыдущая. их нужно сравнить и , если значения отличаются, то счетчик увеличивается. я правильно понял? а в чем, собственно, сложность?

Comment: А можно ли это в таком случае реализовать, если у меня за все строки отвечает 1 переменная string?

Comment: ваша постановка задачи неточная и странная. экстрасенсов нет, посему пробуйте выложенный мной код и говорите, что именно работает некорректно, тогда уже будем подстраивать, а то формулировка с одной перменной совсем ставит в тупик. кто вас ограничивает в количестве переменных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int count = 0;
    String prev = null;        
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if (prev!=null && !line.equals(prev)) count++;
        prev = line;
        System.out.println("Counter: " + count);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, данный код помог с реализацией. Решал задачку на логику, поэтому и постановка вопроса достаточно сложной получилась!